# Spring Security: Allow a public endpoint and not allow other endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

First of all, apologize for the grammatical errors that you can make. My English is not very good.

I'm new with Spring, and I'm trying to create a Basic Auth security.

I'm trying to configure that one endpoint has public access and others admin an user access.

This is my idea:

localhost:8080/api/teacher/findAll -> Public Access

localhost:8080/api/teacher/admin/findAll -> Only ADMIN Access

localhost:8080/api/teacher/user/findAll -> Only USER Access

Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER")
        .and().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/teacher/findAll").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/teacher/admin/findAll").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/teacher/user/findAll").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("*/create/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have one endpoint and execute the necessary logic based on the role(s) of currently logged in user. No need for 3 endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create following End points:

1) localhost:8080/api/teacher/all/findAll -> Public Access

2) localhost:8080/api/teacher/admin/findAll -> Only ADMIN Access

3) localhost:8080/api/teacher/user/findAll -> Only USER Access

Then your configure method would like this:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/teacher/all/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/teacher/admin/**","*/create/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/teacher/user/**").hasRole("USER")
    .and().httpBasic();
}
```